# Using old photos as a basis for streetview google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've recently picked up some old photos of my city, and I was wondering if it is possible to use Google earth/maps to recreate the parts of the city that my photos show.
Most pictures are in street view, so it would be really great to have the old photos as a basis of a street view google map. Some are aireal photos so the "ordinary" map view is also interesting.

Is it possible? What's my first step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs on how to create a custom streetview panorama here:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView

There's also an example of a custom "street view" in the docs, using the reception area of Google's Sydney office here:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple

That example only uses a single source image:

[image: Custom Street View panorama of Google Sydney office]

It looks like the hardest part will be creating either the "stitched" panorama image, or the individual tiles.  Unfortunately Google leaves that to the reader, but there is a link to Wikipedia with some panorama tools that may help:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_applications_(software)